# ¿Conector entre excel y salesforce?

Tags: excel, salesforce

Ando buscando alguna forma de conectar datos de Salesforce (Particularmente Litify) hacia excel, si existiera alguna forma similar a la conexión que existe para salesforce con PowerBI sería genial.